# How would I move my image with a touch and hold on the left and right side of the screen? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I need help with the movement in Swift. I have a `SKSpriteNode` and I need help with touch and drag movement left or right to move and the `SKSpriteNode`. But only the left and right. When I click on the other side than the x position of the picture is to just run over smoothly. Could anyone help how to do it? Thanks.

```
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {

    let rocket = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rocket")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        rocket.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height * 0.8)
        self.addChild(rocket)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        rocket.position = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: self.frame.height * 0.8)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of touch positions and effect, I don't know what you're asking...

Comment: Now, I have this movement, for location on touch. I need movement only x position ..... override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            rocket.position = location
            
        }
    }

Comment: @pulitr You should update your question with this code...Comments are not readable that much in most cases. By the way, rocket.position.x = location.x) will probably do a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this, the rocket animates for 1 second to the location of the touch and then moves with the touch if the user moves their finger.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
let rocket = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rocket")
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    rocket.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height * 0.8)
    self.addChild(rocket)
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        rocket.position = location
    }
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(location, duration: 1/*Or as long as you want it to move*/)
        rocket.runAction(moveAction)
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.